# Unable to proceed in selenium, neither any error occured

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is method to select from dropdown,

```
public void DropSer(String testData, String objectName) {
    System.out.println(testData);
    System.out.println(objectName);
    WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
    Select sel= new Select(ele);
    sel.selectByVisibleText(testData);
}
```

Her i get printed values of testData & objectName but there's no further action,neither an error

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is ele in         Select sel= new Select(ele);

Comment: @iamsankalp89 It's the element declared in the line right above that line.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this function and step through it... what do you see?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.